# ASP EF MVC SELECT Where or

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

quiero hacer un select con **where or where** y estoy tratando de hacer de la siguiente manera, pero ya cuando ejecuto este método

```
  public JsonResult JSONInfoFinTriMonths3()
    {
        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            //Select(m => m.Name).Distinct();
            var categorias = db.HomeInfoFinanciera.Where(s => s.month == 7 && s.month == 8 && s.month == 9);



            return Json(categorias, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Aquí tengo el query que me genera

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[created_at] AS [created_at], 
[Extent1].[lastupdate] AS [lastupdate], 
[Extent1].[id_userCreated] AS [id_userCreated], 
[Extent1].[tipo] AS [tipo], 
[Extent1].[path] AS [path], 
[Extent1].[year] AS [year], 
[Extent1].[month] AS [month], 
[Extent1].[day] AS [day]
FROM [dbo].[HomeInfoFinanciera] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[month] IN (7,8,9)
```

que justo me devuelve todos los datos que deseo.

Aquí estoy llamando al método

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/JSONInfoFinTriMonths3",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response)
        //alert(response);

        var resplength = response.length;
        for (let i = 0; i <= resplength; i++) {

            document.getElementById('months1div')
                .innerHTML += `
                    <li data-filter=".filter-${response[i].year}">
                    ${response[i].year}</li>
                `;
        }
    },

    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, err) {
        //$('#myModalLabel').append(`error: - ${err}`);
        console.log(jqXHR);
        console.log(textStatus);
        console.log(err);

        alert(jqXHR.responseJSON + "JSONInfoFinYears");

    }

});
```

Pero obtengo el error

> alert(jqXHR.responseJSON + "JSONInfoFinYears");

Comment: Por ningún lado veo el "OR". ¿Has probado la herramienta Postman?

Comment: Estás seguro de que `Where(s => s.month == 7 && s.month == 8 && s.month == 9)` se traduce en `WHERE [Extent1].[month] IN (7,8,9)`?. Me lo podrías confirmar por favor.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta pues entiendo que && es and y que || es or, pero con ambos me tira error

Comment: Has probado entonces: `Where(s => s.month == 7 || s.month == 8 || s.month == 9)` ?

Comment: si si, pero nada

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es de interés para alguien aprendiendo, teminé haciendo esto con **Native SQL**
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx

```
   public JsonResult JSONInfoFinTriMonths3()
    {
        using (DBEnt db = new DBEnt())
        {
            //Select(m => m.Name).Distinct();
            //var categorias = db.HomeInfoFinanciera.Where(s => s.month == 7 || s.month == 8 || s.month == 9);
            var categorias = db.HomeInfoFinanciera.SqlQuery
                ("Select * from HomeInfoFinanciera where month = 7 or month = 8 or month = 9")
                .ToList<HomeInfoFinanciera>();
            return Json(categorias, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```